# Week and month picker for Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, date

I am needing date pickers for two cases, so far I have always used JXDatePicker, but that's not what I need now:

I want one date picker especially for weeks of the year and another one for months of the year.

Comment: Can you amplify on what a week chooser might look like.

Comment: Two Comboboxed: one with a list of available weeks, say all the week of the year starting with week number 24. An entry of the box contains the number and the week and the date, say "CW 24, 6/11 - 6/17". Next to to week box is a year box with a list of years with available weeks. When i change the year in the year box, the week box is updated and now shows the available weeks with respect to the selected year

Comment: I haven't see an existing library like this, but it sounds like a straightforward application of `WEEK_OF_YEAR` in `Calendar`. Please edit your question to include these new requirements, as someone else might have seen a suitable drop-in component. You might also post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that outlines what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JCalendar`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcalendar/info) offers `com.toedter.calendar.JMonthChooser`, illustrated [here](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/), which respects the chosen `Locale`.

I don't see a corresponding `JWeekChooser`, but `JCalendar` may be a good framework in which to work.